# The same Style property behaves differently in TextSpan and Text widgets

Tags: flutter

I have the same style properties for a `TextSpan` and `Text` widget

Here is example code:

```
main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
        body: Column(
          children: [
            RichText(
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              text: TextSpan(children: <TextSpan>[
                TextSpan(
                    text: "Score in the ",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 12,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                    )),
              ]),
            ),
            Text("Score in the ", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 12, fontWeight: FontWeight.normal))
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Even though the styles are the same, the TextSpan is giving a "bolder" font. Is it some default property in the TextSpan that I have to change?

Answer (score 1):

`RichText` reads different default values, when not explicitly declared.

If you want to keep the same default style as `Text`, just use `Text.rich`:

```
 Text.rich(
          TextSpan(
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
              fontSize: 12,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
            ),
            children: <TextSpan>[
              TextSpan(text: "Score in the "),
            ],
          ),
        ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You are having this issue because you are using FontWeight.normal which uses the default font weight which is different for TextSpan and Text.  If you set a FontWeight that is the same for both then they will look the same. Below is an example using FontWeight.w500

[image]

Full code here:

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
        body: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            RichText(
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              text: TextSpan(children: <TextSpan>[
                TextSpan(
                    text: "Score in the ",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 12,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                    )),
              ]),
            ),
            Text(" Score in the ",
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 12,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500))
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Setting the fontWeight didn't work in my case. I guess other default proprieties are read.